# Can we add two different NSOperations under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsoperation

I have been trying these for past two days and getting stuck at same point. 
I really would appreciate any help in this. 
Is it possible to add two different NSOperations while loading the applications under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. 
Like I have two different XML URL which parses the data and uses NSOperation to add the data in DB. 
Currently, when I parse two different URLs and use NSOperations, the first NSOperationQueue has the elements from the first URL meaning it is not releasing after it finishes.

Can any one help me in this ?

Sagos

---

```
static NSString *string1 = @"abc.com/abc1.xml";; 
NSURLRequest *URL1 =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:string1]]; 
self.URL1Connection =[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:URL1 delegate:self] autorelease]; 
static NSString *string2 = @"abc.com/abc2.xml";; 
NSURLRequest *URL2 =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string2]]; 
self.URL2Connection =[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:URL2 delegate:self] autorelease];
```

Comment: what do you mean "first NSOperationQueue has the elements from the first URL"? `NSOperationQueue` should contain operations not data objects. Please post some code since it's hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: next time please add the code to your question. Code should never be posted in a comment, as you see it's unreadable.

Comment: How are you creating your queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to prevent more not-answers and red dots by you I'll write a general workflow.

Here is how I would solve this problem. I would create a NSOperation that does both downloading and parsing. And I would ignore the "NSOperation + Networking = You're doing it wrong!"-Sayers for now.

Create a NSOperation with a url and a delegate (this could be the viewcontroller which will show the data), do a synchronous fetch of the data (i.e. `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`) Then parse the data when it's there. And when it's done you tell the delegate that the data is ready.

This will eliminate the slightly more complex task to distinguish between an arbitrary number of xml downloads. Because (I think) this was your problem. You've added two NSOperations to the queue when one of them was finished. So the other one was running with incomplete data. And if I had to make a guess I would say you mixed the downloaded data of both too.

Add the NSOperationQueue to you appDelegate and add the NSOperations to this queue.

---

As a side-note, when you have comments or additions to your question you should put them in the question. Answers are for answers to the question only. If you want to post more than once, and like the dialogue with other developers you should have a look at a forum. For example [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/) or [this](http://developer.apple.com/devforums/) but there are many more. But they usually suck, and nobody (exaggeration) gives good answers there because nobody want's to read 50 posts on 3 pages to get the picture. That's why we try to put everything relevant into the question. It's much easier for people who want to answer your question.

So next time if somebody asks for more information or code please edit the question and add the information there. You should never post an answer if you don't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really never thought that there would be distinction in between writing your answer and asking a question because I could not fit my answer in the comments part. So I thought to add in answer section. But I will try to add a delegate with the viewcontroller . But one more question, I am new to iPhone programming and not sure how should I add my nsoperationqueue to my appdelegate. I have used seismicXML example but its only for one URL connection.

Answer (score 0):

@fluchtpunkt:

I have two different XML URLs which has data in each one of them which I populate separately. Both the XML File structure are different and hence I have two different NSOperations to parse through the file and add them in their database. 
I am not sure how to add the NSOperation in my viewcontroller which if possible will be of great help, since I am have two different View Controllers for both the URLs.